# Problema com FOREACH PHP

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, foreach, phtml

Meu problema é que meu foreach só funciona quando no retorno em XML, vem com mais de um valor na array, mas quando vem apenas 1, ele não funciona.

O retorno em XML quando vem mais de 1 valor seria assim:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <HSONLINE>
      <CONSIGNACAO id="1">
      ...Valores do array...
      </CONSIGNACAO>
      <CONSIGNACAO id="2">
      ...Valores do array...
      </CONSIGNACAO>
  </HSONLINE
</NewDataSet>
```

E quando o XML vem com apenas 1 valor seria assim:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <HSONLINE>
      <CONSIGNACAO id="1">
      ...Valores do array...
      </CONSIGNACAO>
  </HSONLINE
</NewDataSet>
```

Este é meu código em PHTML:

```
foreach($consignado as $registro){

//Verifico se a variavel não é um array
if(!is_array(current($retorno['HSONLINE']['CONSIGNACAO']))){
    $registro = $retorno['HSONLINE']['CONSIGNACAO'];
}

//Declado as variaveis
$nomeBanco = $registro['NOME_BANCO'];
$dataInicio = $registro['DATA_INICIO'];
$parcelaTotal = $registro['PARCELA_TOTAL'];
$dataTermino = $registro['DATA_TERMINO'];
$exclusaoBanco = $registro['EXCLUIDO_BANCO'];
$valorEmprestado = $registro['VALOR_EMPRESTIMO'];
$valorParcela = $registro['VALOR_PARCELA'];

$contrato = $registro['CONTRATO'];
$fimDesconto = $registro['FIM_DESCONTO'];
$excluidoAPS = $registro['EXCLUIDO_APS'];
$codigoBanco = $registro['CODIGO_BANCO'];
$situacao = $registro['SITUACAO'];
$dataConsignacao = $registro['DATA_CONSIGNACAO'];
$banco = $registro['BANCO'];


$tipo = $registro['TIPO'];
$tipoCodigo = $registro['TIPO_CODIGO'];
$competenciaDesconto = $registro['COMPETENCIA_DESCONTO'];
$tipoDesconto = $registro['TIPO_DESCONTO'];
$parcelasAberto = $registro['PARCELAS_ABERTO'];
$saldoAproximado = $registro['SALDO_APROXIMADO'];
$dataAverbacao = $registro['DATA_AVERBACAO'];




$pintar=" 
    <table class=\"table-custom\">      
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                    <td class=\"banco2\">$nomeBanco</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataInicio</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$parcelaTotal</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataTermino</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$exclusaoBanco</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$valorEmprestado</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$valorParcela</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=\"tr-esconder1\">
                                    <td class=\"contrato2\">$contrato</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$fimDesconto</td>  
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$excluidoAPS</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$codigoBanco</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$situacao</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataConsignacao</td> 
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$banco</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class=\"tr-esconder1\">
                                    <td class=\"contrato2\">$tipo</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$tipoCodigo</td>  
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$competenciaDesconto</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$tipoDesconto</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$parcelasAberto</td> 
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$saldoAproximado</td> 
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataAverbacao</td> 
            </tr>
            <br/>
        </tbody>
    </table>";

$pintar = str_replace(">Array<", ">Não Informado<", $pintar);
echo $pintar;

    //Aqui ele faz a verificação se não é um array e da o break
    if(!is_array(current($retorno['HSONLINE']['CONSIGNACAO']))){
        break;
    }
}
```

O layout da página fica assim, quando o XML vem com mais de 1 CONSIGNACAO
[image: Quando o retorno vem com mais de 1 informação]

E fica assim quando vem apenas um:
[image: Quando o retorno vem com apenas 1 informação]

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Não falta um `>` após o `</HSONLINE`?

Comment: Isso foi erro meu, mas no XML que eu uso está certo

Answer (score 0):

Tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas alterações no seu codigo. Dentre elas, alterei o acesso aos elementos da forma `$chave=>$valor` para object operator `->`. Também comentei ambos os laços if dentro do foreach (essa checagem não parece relevante, uma vez que o foreach já as realiza, ou são inficientes se alguma das propriedades que vão ser acessadas não existirem). Além disso criei um pequeno arquivo xml (seguindo o modelo que você passou) para testar a execução do codigo. Então o arquivo `xml.xml` ficou assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <HSONLINE>
    <CONSIGNACAO id="1">
        <NOME_BANCO>Campo 1</NOME_BANCO>
        <DATA_INICIO>Campo 2</DATA_INICIO>
        <PARCELA_TOTAL>Campo 3</PARCELA_TOTAL>
        <DATA_TERMINO>Campo 4</DATA_TERMINO>
        <EXCLUIDO_BANCO>Campo 5</EXCLUIDO_BANCO>
        <VALOR_EMPRESTIMO>Campo 6</VALOR_EMPRESTIMO>
        <VALOR_PARCELA>Campo 7</VALOR_PARCELA>

        <CONTRATO>Campo 8</CONTRATO>
        <FIM_DESCONTO>Campo 9</FIM_DESCONTO>
        <EXCLUIDO_APS>Campo 10</EXCLUIDO_APS>
        <CODIGO_BANCO>Campo 11</CODIGO_BANCO>
        <SITUACAO>Campo 12</SITUACAO>
        <DATA_CONSIGNACAO>Campo 13</DATA_CONSIGNACAO>
        <BANCO>Campo 14</BANCO>

        <TIPO>Campo 15</TIPO>
        <TIPO_CODIGO>Campo 15</TIPO_CODIGO>
        <COMPETENCIA_DESCONTO>Campo 15</COMPETENCIA_DESCONTO>
        <TIPO_DESCONTO>Campo 15</TIPO_DESCONTO>
        <PARCELAS_ABERTO>Campo 15</PARCELAS_ABERTO>
        <SALDO_APROXIMADO>Campo 15</SALDO_APROXIMADO>
        <DATA_AVERBACAO>Campo 15</DATA_AVERBACAO>

    </CONSIGNACAO>
    <CONSIGNACAO id="2">
        <NOME_BANCO>Campo 1</NOME_BANCO>
        <DATA_INICIO>Campo 2</DATA_INICIO>
        <PARCELA_TOTAL>Campo 3</PARCELA_TOTAL>
        <DATA_TERMINO>Campo 4</DATA_TERMINO>
        <EXCLUIDO_BANCO>Campo 5</EXCLUIDO_BANCO>
        <VALOR_EMPRESTIMO>Campo 6</VALOR_EMPRESTIMO>
        <VALOR_PARCELA>Campo 7</VALOR_PARCELA>

        <CONTRATO>Campo 8</CONTRATO>
        <FIM_DESCONTO>Campo 9</FIM_DESCONTO>
        <EXCLUIDO_APS>Campo 10</EXCLUIDO_APS>
        <CODIGO_BANCO>Campo 11</CODIGO_BANCO>
        <SITUACAO>Campo 12</SITUACAO>
        <DATA_CONSIGNACAO>Campo 13</DATA_CONSIGNACAO>
        <BANCO>Campo 14</BANCO>

        <TIPO>Campo 15</TIPO>
        <TIPO_CODIGO>Campo 15</TIPO_CODIGO>
        <COMPETENCIA_DESCONTO>Campo 15</COMPETENCIA_DESCONTO>
        <TIPO_DESCONTO>Campo 15</TIPO_DESCONTO>
        <PARCELAS_ABERTO>Campo 15</PARCELAS_ABERTO>
        <SALDO_APROXIMADO>Campo 15</SALDO_APROXIMADO>
        <DATA_AVERBACAO>Campo 15</DATA_AVERBACAO>
    </CONSIGNACAO>
  </HSONLINE>
</NewDataSet>
```

Como pode ser visto o arquivo xml possui dois elementos CONSIGNACAO (então deu para testar com muitos elementos e com apenas um elemento).

Já o código PHP ficou assim:

```
<?php

$retorno = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

//retorna todos os elementos CONSIGNACAO
$consignado = $retorno->HSONLINE;

foreach($consignado->children() as $registro){
    //melhor seria checar se as propriedades que vão ser acessadas existem
    /*if(!is_array(current($retorno->HSONLINE->CONSIGNACAO))){
        $registro = $retorno->HSONLINE->CONSIGNACAO;
    }*/

    //Declado as variaveis
    $nomeBanco = $registro->NOME_BANCO;
    $dataInicio = $registro->DATA_INICIO;
    $parcelaTotal = $registro->PARCELA_TOTAL;
    $dataTermino = $registro->DATA_TERMINO;
    $exclusaoBanco = $registro->EXCLUIDO_BANCO;
    $valorEmprestado = $registro->VALOR_EMPRESTIMO;
    $valorParcela = $registro->VALOR_PARCELA;

    $contrato = $registro->CONTRATO;
    $fimDesconto = $registro->FIM_DESCONTO;
    $excluidoAPS = $registro->EXCLUIDO_APS;
    $codigoBanco = $registro->CODIGO_BANCO;
    $situacao = $registro->SITUACAO;
    $dataConsignacao = $registro->DATA_CONSIGNACAO;
    $banco = $registro->BANCO;


    $tipo = $registro->TIPO;
    $tipoCodigo = $registro->TIPO_CODIGO;
    $competenciaDesconto = $registro->COMPETENCIA_DESCONTO;
    $tipoDesconto = $registro->TIPO_DESCONTO;
    $parcelasAberto = $registro->PARCELAS_ABERTO;
    $saldoAproximado = $registro->SALDO_APROXIMADO;
    $dataAverbacao = $registro->DATA_AVERBACAO;

    $pintar=" 
    <table class=\"table-custom\">      
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                    <td class=\"banco2\">$nomeBanco</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataInicio</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$parcelaTotal</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataTermino</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$exclusaoBanco</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$valorEmprestado</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$valorParcela</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=\"tr-esconder1\">
                                    <td class=\"contrato2\">$contrato</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$fimDesconto</td>  
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$excluidoAPS</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$codigoBanco</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$situacao</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataConsignacao</td> 
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$banco</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class=\"tr-esconder1\">
                                    <td class=\"contrato2\">$tipo</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$tipoCodigo</td>  
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$competenciaDesconto</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$tipoDesconto</td>
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$parcelasAberto</td> 
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$saldoAproximado</td> 
                                    <td class=\"tdCustom2\">$dataAverbacao</td> 
            </tr>
            <br/>
        </tbody>
    </table>";

    $pintar = str_replace(">Array<", ">Não Informado<", $pintar);
    echo $pintar;

    //o foreach verifica isso
    /*if(!is_array(current($retorno['HSONLINE']['CONSIGNACAO']))){
        break;
    }*/
}
```

Quando o arquivo xml possui variaos elementos é gerada a seguinte saida (como não tem as classes css algumas linhas não ficarão ocultas):

```html
 <table class="table-custom">      
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                    <td class="banco2">Campo 1</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 2</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 3</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 4</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 5</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 6</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-esconder1">
                                    <td class="contrato2">Campo 8</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 9</td>  
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 10</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 11</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 12</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 13</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 14</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-esconder1">
                                    <td class="contrato2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>  
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
            </tr>
            <br/>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <table class="table-custom">      
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                    <td class="banco2">Campo 1</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 2</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 3</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 4</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 5</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 6</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-esconder1">
                                    <td class="contrato2">Campo 8</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 9</td>  
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 10</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 11</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 12</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 13</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 14</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-esconder1">
                                    <td class="contrato2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>  
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
            </tr>
            <br/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

E com apenas um elemento no arquivo xml tem a saida esperada também:

```html
<table class="table-custom">      
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                    <td class="banco2">Campo 1</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 2</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 3</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 4</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 5</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 6</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-esconder1">
                                    <td class="contrato2">Campo 8</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 9</td>  
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 10</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 11</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 12</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 13</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 14</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-esconder1">
                                    <td class="contrato2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>  
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
                                    <td class="tdCustom2">Campo 15</td> 
            </tr>
            <br/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```